# Android Studio GAE Project Deploy: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java7

Tags: google-app-engine, android-studio

I have a Google App Engine project in Android Studio. In the past I have successfully deployed to my project to GAE many times. However, some project setting has changed and I can no longer deploy. I get the message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.class in /Users/rob/AndroidStudioProjects/SpeedyMovingInventory/backend/build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1-m02.jar
Unable to update app: Class file is Java 8 but max supported is Java 7: javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.class in /Users/rob/AndroidStudioProjects/SpeedyMovingInventory/backend/build/exploded-app/WEB-INF/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1-m02.jar
Please see the logs [/var/folders/cn/3ktx4pj50hs7338v88b0sckh0000gn/T/appcfg3087406806803083082.log] for further information.
```

I have tried to set the source and target compatibility in my build.gradle, it is shown below:

```
// If you would like more information on the gradle-appengine-plugin please refer to the github page
// https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.34'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {

    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.34'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.34'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.2'
    compile 'net.sargue:mailgun:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Hamcrest matching
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    testCompile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '/Users/rob/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.34/lib/impl')
    testCompile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '/Users/rob/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.34/lib/testing')
}


appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }

}
```

I have also used Android Studio to generate a sample GAE module and successfully deployed the sample to GAE. I compared the gradle files and settings and I don't see any differences. Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I have figured a fix. The library 'net.sargue:mailgun:1.0.0' apparently has a dependency of some sort on a java 8 lib (or something along those lines). I don't know why this hasn't caused me issues in the past, but it is now. Upgrading the lib to 'net.sargue:mailgun:1.3.2" resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a conversation with the author of the mailgun library:
https://github.com/sargue/mailgun/issues/11

He had a dependency which were updated to Java 8, he fixed it in the new release.